# JavaScript Error On Display table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flexigrid

When I use this piece of code:

```
$("#flex1").flexigrid({
    colModel : [
            {display :'Customer ID',name : 'customer_id',width : 100,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            {display :'Customer Full Name',name : 'customer_fullname',width : 130,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            {display : 'Admin License No',name : 'admin_license_number',width : 130,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            {display : 'Admin License Key',name : 'admin_license_key',width : 130,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            {display : 'User License Number',name : 'user_license_number',width : 130,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            {display : 'ska2',name : '',width : 130,sortable : true,align : 'left'}, 
            ],
    sortname: "customer_id",
    sortorder: "asc",
    usepager: true,
    title: 'List',
    useRp: true,
    rp: 10,
    showTableToggleBtn: true,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
});
```

an error occurs and nothing is displayed:

> Error: Expected Identifier, string or number.

Right now I'm using PHP4 and try implement after I try it on PHP5 above.

Comment: What does the version of PHP have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're testing in IE8 or below and those trailing comma's in your object are error:

For example,

```
 height: 500, <--
});
```

Comment: Also trailing comma in 'colModel' array.

Comment: @IvanGL, believe or not that one is legal